# How do I monitor ASP errors

Tags: asp.net

I come from a mainly PHP background and make good use of the Apache error logs by using the command line. I've recently been handed a large ASP/ASP.NET project that I need to make changes to, where do I find the error logs on a Windows IIS setup so that I may troubleshoot some issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said which version of IIS you are using. In IIS 6, the HTTP error log is located in systemroot\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR.

ASP.net itself won't produce any error logs unless it is configured to do so.  There are many ways to do this for example with Log4net, Enterprise Library Logging Application Block, trace diagnostics or a roll your own approach.

Have a look in the web.config file and see if/how logging is configured for the application.